# I'm confused about inheritance of conversion operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, conversion-operator

Consider following program: (See live demo [here.](http://ideone.com/ECR852))

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
    int s{9};
    public:
        operator int()
        {
            return s;
        }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
    int s{18};
};
int main()
{
    Base b;
    int s=b;
    std::cout<<s<<'\n';

    Derived d;
    int m=d;
    std::cout<<m;
}
```

Output of program is:

9

9

Here, the conversion operator of `Base` class is inherited, so the initialization of `m` variable is valid.

But now I want to print the value of `s` data member that belongs to Derived. How can I do this?

Is it necessary to rewrite conversion operator for derived class also? Can't I reuse the same `Base` class conversion operator?

Comment: @juanchopanza: outcome of program is : 9 9

Comment: @juanchopanza: what?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Can't I reuse the same Base class conversion operator?Is it necessary to rewrite conversion operator for derived class also?

Comment: @juanchopanza: ok done. now?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I still not get answer of my question.

Comment: I think there already is an answer. If not, then you need to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `s` parameter of `Base` is shadowed in `Derived`, but since conversion operator in in `Base` class, `Base::s` is used inside it.
You can do this:

```
class Base
{
    int s{9};
    public:
        Base() {}
        Base(int v) : s(v) {}
        operator int()
        {
            return s;
        }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(18)
    {
    }
};
```

or write its own conversion operator in `Derived`.

Comment: So, Base class has no knowledge about Derived class' members that's why it is necessary to rewrite conversion function for derived also. right?